# Backup Azure Data Factoryv2 configurations to JSON

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

This is a bit of a generic question - I've got an ADFv2 instance with a number of fiddly datasets (namely they require custom queries to make them behave) and a number of relatively complex pipelines.

So far, I've been creating all of these via the Web Page - but I've got to the point where I'm looking to backup the entirety of the config to a series of JSON files, so I can store it in somewhere like Git, and if needed, recreate the whole thing from scratch using Powershell.

Now, I'm aware that from the GUI, there is the option of clicking for the ARM code - which will display the relevant JSON - I'm however looking for a way (probably via PS) to auto-magically backup the entire instance (Connections, Datasets, Pipelines etc. etc.) to multiple JSON files.

Is anyone aware if this functionality natively exists? or if there is a tool to do it? or is the only way to build a big Powershell loop, looping through all the contents and outputting each to JSON?

I appreciate any input.

Thanks

Comment: Click the Github button and commit it to a repo. There's a lot of links describing how to do this, including on the actual title page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Click the Set up Code Repository option.

Then you can configure with Azure DevOps or Github.